# Minitest and Devise integration test is not updating the resource/model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, minitest

So I have this resource (User) that I am trying to test the updating of. I am using Ruby 3.0.1, Rails 6.1.4, Devise 4.8.1, and Recaptcha 5.8.1. Here's the User:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :trackable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable, :confirmable

  include Elasticsearch::Model

  scope :visible_to_public, -> { where(searchable: true) }
  scope :activated, -> { where('users.confirmed_at IS NOT NULL') }

  index_name "users-#{Rails.env}"
  
  has_one_attached :avatar
  has_many :widgets, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :active_relationships, class_name:  "Relationship",
                                  foreign_key: "follower_id",
                                  dependent:   :destroy
  has_many :passive_relationships, class_name:  "Relationship",
                                   foreign_key: "followed_id",
                                   dependent:   :destroy
  has_many :following, through: :active_relationships, source: :followed
  has_many :followers, through: :passive_relationships, source: :follower
  has_many :reports, dependent:   :destroy
  has_many :comments, dependent:   :destroy

  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: true
```

Here's the test:

```
test "successful edit" do
    sign_in @user, scope: :user
    name  = "Foo Bar"
    handle  = "MrFoo"
    put user_registration_path, params: { user: { name:  name,
                                              username: handle,
                                              email: @user.email,
                                              password: '',
                                              password_confirmation:'',
                                              current_password: @user.current_password }}
    assert_response :success
    puts "User Errors: #{@user.errors.full_messages}\n"
    @user.reload
    puts "User: #{@user.inspect}\n"
    assert_equal name,  @user.name
    assert_equal handle, @user.username
  end
```

The assert_equal name is failing and the User errors from the put statement in the test is an empty array '[]'.

I created a Devise Registration controller so I could use the recaptcha gem. It has very little code. Here it is:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_action :configure_sign_up_params, only: [:create]
  before_action :configure_account_update_params, only: [:update]

def update
    if verify_recaptcha
      super
    else
      self.resource = resource_class.new sign_up_params
      flash.now[:error] = "Recaptcha cannot be blank; please try again"
      redirect_to edit_user_registration_path
    end
  end

 protected

  # If you have extra params to permit, append them to the sanitizer.
  def configure_sign_up_params
    sign_up_attrs = [:password, :password_confirmation, :name, :username, :avatar]
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [sign_up_attrs])
  end


  # If you have extra params to permit, append them to the sanitizer.
  def configure_account_update_params
    update_attrs = [:password, :password_confirmation, :current_password, :name, :username, :avatar]
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [update_attrs])
  end

end
```

Here's the log:

```
-----------------------------------
UsersEditTest: test_successful_edit
-----------------------------------
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.4ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?[0m  [["id", 688598839], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?[0m  [["id", 838564783], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Started PUT "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2022-01-25 17:32:25 -0500
  [1m[36mTRANSACTION (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[35mSAVEPOINT active_record_1[0m
  [1m[36mUser Update (0.4ms)[0m  [1m[33mUPDATE "users" SET "updated_at" = ?, "sign_in_count" = ?, "current_sign_in_at" = ?, "last_sign_in_at" = ?, "current_sign_in_ip" = ?, "last_sign_in_ip" = ? WHERE "users"."id" = ?[0m  [["updated_at", "2022-01-25 22:32:25.237068"], ["sign_in_count", 1], ["current_sign_in_at", "2022-01-25 22:32:25.236226"], ["last_sign_in_at", "2022-01-25 22:32:25.236226"], ["current_sign_in_ip", "127.0.0.1"], ["last_sign_in_ip", "127.0.0.1"], ["id", 688598839]]
  [1m[36mActiveStorage::Attachment Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "active_storage_attachments".* FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = ? AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = ? AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = ? LIMIT ?[0m  [["record_id", 688598839], ["record_type", "User"], ["name", "avatar"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[36mUser Exists? (0.2ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = ? AND "users"."id" != ? LIMIT ?[0m  [["email", "nick@example.com"], ["id", 688598839], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[36mActiveStorage::Blob Load (0.2ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "active_storage_blobs".* FROM "active_storage_blobs" INNER JOIN "active_storage_attachments" ON "active_storage_blobs"."id" = "active_storage_attachments"."blob_id" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = ? AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = ? AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = ? LIMIT ?[0m  [["record_id", 688598839], ["record_type", "User"], ["name", "avatar"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[36mActiveStorage::Blob Create (0.4ms)[0m  [1m[32mINSERT INTO "active_storage_blobs" ("key", "filename", "content_type", "metadata", "byte_size", "checksum", "created_at", "service_name") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)[0m  [["key", "c8w5ycv9gy4c67phehpbdvwxdigo"], ["filename", "default_avatar2.png"], ["content_type", "image/png"], ["metadata", "{\"identified\":true}"], ["byte_size", 15693], ["checksum", "4IDAjCeSqMrDM9F9s68Wtw=="], ["created_at", "2022-01-25 22:32:25.271303"], ["service_name", "test"]]
  [1m[36mActiveStorage::Attachment Create (0.3ms)[0m  [1m[32mINSERT INTO "active_storage_attachments" ("name", "record_type", "record_id", "blob_id", "created_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)[0m  [["name", "avatar"], ["record_type", "User"], ["record_id", 688598839], ["blob_id", 1], ["created_at", "2022-01-25 22:32:25.273083"]]
  [1m[36mUser Update (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[33mUPDATE "users" SET "updated_at" = ? WHERE "users"."id" = ?[0m  [["updated_at", "2022-01-25 22:32:25.274730"], ["id", 688598839]]
  [1m[36mTRANSACTION (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[35mRELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1[0m
[36m  Disk Storage (0.7ms) [0m[32mUploaded file to key: c8w5ycv9gy4c67phehpbdvwxdigo (checksum: 4IDAjCeSqMrDM9F9s68Wtw==)[0m
[ActiveJob] Enqueued ActiveStorage::AnalyzeJob (Job ID: c2fffb8c-2df4-4224-a96c-38e6185954b8) to Test(active_storage_analysis) with arguments: #<GlobalID:0x000055cf7cde5098 @uri=#<URI::GID gid://saverd/ActiveStorage::Blob/1>>
Processing by Users::RegistrationsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"user"=>{"name"=>"Foo Bar", "username"=>"MrFoo", "email"=>"nick@example.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "current_password"=>"[FILTERED]"}}
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?[0m  [["id", 688598839], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[36mUser Exists? (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = ? AND "users"."id" != ? LIMIT ?[0m  [["email", "nick@example.com"], ["id", 688598839], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendering layout layouts/application.html.erb
  Rendering users/registrations/edit.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered users/shared/_error_messages.html.erb (Duration: 1.5ms | Allocations: 949)
  [1m[36mActiveStorage::Attachment Load (0.3ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "active_storage_attachments".* FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = ? AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = ? AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = ? LIMIT ?[0m  [["record_id", 688598839], ["record_type", "User"], ["name", "avatar"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[36mActiveStorage::Blob Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "active_storage_blobs".* FROM "active_storage_blobs" WHERE "active_storage_blobs"."id" = ? LIMIT ?[0m  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendered users/registrations/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 12.9ms | Allocations: 7556)
[Webpacker] Everything's up-to-date. Nothing to do
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (Duration: 0.3ms | Allocations: 85)
  Rendered layouts/_head.html.erb (Duration: 4.1ms | Allocations: 1988)
[36m  Disk Storage (0.1ms) [0m[34mChecked if file exists at key: variants/c8w5ycv9gy4c67phehpbdvwxdigo/f0565870533d712d9f81cf6c91b03ed2afd53144cf67b4fdca912bf91444366f (no)[0m
[36m  Disk Storage (0.1ms) [0m[34mDownloaded file from key: c8w5ycv9gy4c67phehpbdvwxdigo[0m
[36m  Disk Storage (0.4ms) [0m[32mUploaded file to key: variants/c8w5ycv9gy4c67phehpbdvwxdigo/f0565870533d712d9f81cf6c91b03ed2afd53144cf67b4fdca912bf91444366f[0m
  [1m[35m (0.2ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT COUNT(*) FROM "widgets" WHERE "widgets"."user_id" = ?[0m  [["user_id", 688598839]]
  Rendered shared/_user_info.html.erb (Duration: 90.4ms | Allocations: 3974)
  [1m[35m (0.2ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" INNER JOIN "relationships" ON "users"."id" = "relationships"."followed_id" WHERE "relationships"."follower_id" = ?[0m  [["follower_id", 688598839]]
  [1m[35m (0.2ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" INNER JOIN "relationships" ON "users"."id" = "relationships"."follower_id" WHERE "relationships"."followed_id" = ?[0m  [["followed_id", 688598839]]
  Rendered shared/_stats.html.erb (Duration: 10.6ms | Allocations: 2077)
  Rendered shared/_user_widget_search.html.erb (Duration: 2.4ms | Allocations: 429)
  [1m[35m (0.3ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT COUNT(*) FROM "widgets" INNER JOIN "widget_references" ON "widgets"."id" = "widget_references"."referenced_id" WHERE "widget_references"."referencer_id" = ?[0m  [["referencer_id", 688598839]]
  [1m[35mCACHE  (0.0ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT COUNT(*) FROM "widgets" WHERE "widgets"."user_id" = ?[0m  [["user_id", 688598839]]
  Rendered shared/_widget_box.html.erb (Duration: 5.2ms | Allocations: 1066)
  [1m[35m (0.2ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT COUNT(*) FROM "categories"[0m
  [1m[36mCategory Load (0.3ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" ORDER BY "categories"."sequence" ASC[0m
  Rendered shared/_categories.html.erb (Duration: 11.0ms | Allocations: 4993)
  Rendered shared/_sidebar_user.html.erb (Duration: 133.4ms | Allocations: 13724)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (Duration: 136.2ms | Allocations: 14611)
  Rendered shared/_alerts.html.erb (Duration: 0.7ms | Allocations: 185)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (Duration: 1.0ms | Allocations: 310)
  Rendered layout layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 158.3ms | Allocations: 25688)
Completed 200 OK in 172ms (Views: 159.2ms | ActiveRecord: 2.1ms | Allocations: 33566)
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?[0m  [["id", 688598839], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[36mTRANSACTION (0.4ms)[0m  [1m[31mrollback transaction[0m
```

When I run the server and do this manually it works. I also have turbo disabled on all of my forms. I'm stumped.

Comment: Have you tried to remove recaptcha and run test? Does it make the test pass?
Also, I think you may need `id: @user.id` in params for update.

Comment: Tried it without recaptcha and the result is the same. Also, I don't believe Devise requires the user id. The params that are sent match the normal server request with the exception of the authenticity_token and commit keys. I also tried resetting the test database a few times, and stopping spring. Unfortunately it didn't help.